# How can I take a screenshot in a pre-defined area by X and Y coordinates without needing to drag my mouse imprecisely over the area?

Tags: windows-10, screenshot, snipping

I just want to screenshot certain areas of my screen based on precise coordinates.  Instead of dragging the mouse across the screen or taking a full screen screenshot, I'd like to type in the boundaries.  How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want to really screenshot using precise XY coordinates or you want to screenshot a window (browser)?

Comment: I'd like it to be as precise and to give me as much control as possible, yes.  When using something like Snipping Tool, if it gave me the ability to readjust the screen shot area before committing, then that would be useful.